# HTTP ERROR 500 on upload page - Lightsail (AMI)

Tags: 500-error

I have a PHP based site on an Amazon Lightsail (AMI) instance. This site was recently moved from Godaddy.

The entire website works fine, except;

1. Random '*/?>' on multiple pages.
2. HTTP ERROR 500 on the page that is used to upload files to the server.

Things I have tried;

1. Changing file permissions. Current file permissions are set to (same on the old server). File permissions are same on all files in html

   [ec2-user@ip www]$ ll
   total 20
   drwxrwsr-x  2 root www 4096 Jan 19 16:56 cgi-bin
   drwxrwsr-x  3 root www 4096 Apr 10 14:19 error
   drwxrwsr-x 29 root www 4096 Apr 10 19:07 html
   drwxrwsr-x  3 root www 4096 Apr 10 14:19 icons
   drwxrwsr-x  2 root www 4096 Apr 10 14:19 noindex

File permission on the actual file;

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user www   7144 Apr 10 18:51 out.AddDocument.php
```

2. Changed AllowOverride to All (from None) in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf for
3. Contents of the php (out.AddDocument.php); https://pastebin.com/JyG20qpX

Comment: What do your error logs say for that 500 error?

Comment: @EEAA♦ This is a paste of the /var/log/httpd/access_log, here: https://pastebin.com/xFX8F1K2

Do you need to see any other log file?

Comment: Please do not put information that's relevant to your question, instead edit the information *directly* into your question, not via a link.

Comment: And you need your application error log, not the web access log.

Comment: I am sorry, I will paste the information in my original question from now on. Can you please let me know where I will find the application error log?

Comment: @EEAA so my error_log files are not being written to as well. I created a test.php in a new folder that tries to connect to a non-existent db. when I goto test.php via a browser it gives me error 500 as well. Does this help?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue at the end. I never configured php.ini correctly after installing it, went through php.ini and configured it correctly, everything started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue at the end. I never configured php.ini correctly after installing it, went through php.ini and configured it correctly, everything started working